# Error handling for async functions in rxjs map

Tags: rxjs

I am trying to learn reactive programming using `rxjs`

Here is the problem. This block takes an array of string URLs `urls`
and run `httpGet` fetch response. Do some transformation and returns
all the response in an array.

This works if the there is no error in `httpGet`

How do I catch the error thrown by `httpGet`?

```
  lastValueFrom(
    from(urls).pipe(
      map(httpGet),
      concatAll(),
      map(({ body, status }: Response) => ({
        [status === 200 ? "OK" : "FAILURE"]:
          JSON.parse(body)?.message || "No message found",
      })),
      catchError(() =>
        of({
          FAILURE: "Something went wrong",
        })
      ),
      toArray()
    )
  );
```

Comment: what do you want to do when error happened?

Comment: I want to return`{
          FAILURE: "Something went wrong",
        }`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the following:

- code the "happy path" logic as first part of your pipe
- in the function passed to the `map` operator place the logic that throws an error in case of `STATUS` different from `200`
- place a `catchError` as last operator in the pipe to intercept the error case and return what you want to return in this case

So the code would look like this

```
from(urls).pipe(
    map(httpGet),
    concatAll(),
    map(({ body, status }) => {
      if (status !== 200) {
        throw new Error('an error occured');
      }
      return {
        OK: body ? body : 'No message found',
      };
    }),
    toArray(),
    catchError((err) => {
      console.log('ERROR: ', err);
      return of({
        FAILURE: 'Something went wrong',
      });
    })
  );
```

You can look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-a8laqe?file=index.ts) for an example

Comment: This doesn't work if you use an invalid URL. For example 

`httpGet` returns `of( new Error('Valid token not returned')).pipe(delay(100));`